# substring using bat command

Tags: substring, batch-file

I have the following thing in my bat file. say

set path=c:\temp\test

so basically i want to have an output which would give me the result as c:\temp\

i didnt find any indexof equivalent in bat command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Background:

```
>set fullname=c:\mypath\oldfile
>set changedname=%fullname:oldfile=newfile%
>echo %changedname%
c:\mypath\newfile
```

Applied to problem:

```
> set fullname=c:\mypath\oldfile
> set pathonly=%fullname:oldfile=%
> echo %pathonly%
c:\mypath\
```

Answer (score 3):

A question that really makes me wish [4DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4DOS) still existed. However, I found something that might help in [`alt.msdos.batch.nt`](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.msdos.batch.nt/msg/923423bf3143fcdd?pli=1). The manual page for `set` seems to contain most of the same information. (command `help set`)

```
set test=123456789

rem extract chars 0-5 from the variable test
set test=%test:~0,5%

echo %test%
```

(Note: tested on Windows XP SP3)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want that?

[Johannes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690382/substring-using-bat-command/2692177#2692177) answer is a possible solution, but maybe the path you refer to is being (or could be) passed as an argument to the script, in which case you can use the following syntax:

```
REM Extracts the drive and path from argument %1
SET p=%~dp1
```

Alternatively you may combine `..` and the script path (`%0`):

```
REM Sets p to a sibling of the script directory
SET p=%~dp0..\test
```

Answer (score 0):

Naïve substrings have the problem that you have to adjust them every time your paths change and it isn't a generic solution to the problem.

The following batch file gives a proof of concept how you might do the truncation part of the path:

```
@echo off
set foo=C:\Temp\Test
call :strip
echo %foo%
goto :eof

:strip
if not "%foo:~-1%"=="\" (
    set foo=%foo:~0,-1%
    goto :strip
)
goto :eof
```

It's hard-coded to a single variable but that is easily fixed if needed.

The core part here is the `strip` subroutine which loops and cuts off the last character of the string until a backslash is found. This effectively removes the last part of the path.