# Retrieve a variable length substring based on a delimiting character

Tags: batch-file, dos

I'm tryin to make a simple command to strip everything after a word, and echo the result.

Example:

> street-ct-2a21340565364563563
>   thiswouldbedifferent-ss-3c63456345645635634
>   andthiscouldbesomethingelse-we-5d23453453634563456

removing everything expect the first section

Something like:

> street-ct-221340565364563563

would result in:

> street

This isn't being saved in a txt file or anything, is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [substring using bat command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690382/substring-using-bat-command)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a duplicate, because the OP doesn't need a fixed character count substring, but rather a dynamic one based on a delimiting character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** Assuming that the part you are trying to extract has variable length, this seems to be an even better solution:

```
set str=street-ct-2a21340565364563563
for /f "delims=-" %%a in ("%str%") do set part=%%a
echo.%part%
```

In that snippet, we split the string whenever a "`-`" occurs, and then assign the first part of the split string to the "`part`" variable. Additional examples on how to use `for` to split strings can be found [here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.SplitString).

---

According to [this reference](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) you could do something like this:

```
set str=street-ct-2a21340565364563563
set substr=%str:~0,6%
echo.%substr%
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tired this. my bad forgot to mention each line isnt the same so its not possible to do a count.

Comment: Hey! I know this is an old post but I was curious why you put a `.` directly after the echo statement in the last line? What does it do?

Comment: I didn't remember, but I've managed [to Google it](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/08e80dec-f915-49ab-ac76-c0c5e33bbe75/quotechoquot-command-in-cmdexe?forum=ITCG) :)